# How to read table on scala spark using partitionColumn of varchar datatype?

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

Is it possible to give a partitionColumn of varchar datatype?
The table that I want to read doesn't have a primary key and all the columns are of varchar data type. Is there any way to read from jdbc with partitionColumn as a varchar type?

```
var finaldataframe = spark.read.format("jdbc")
.option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
.option("database",db)
.option("url", url)
.option("dbtable", table_name)
.option("numPartitions", partitions)
.option("partitionColumn", pm_key)
.option("lowerbound", w_minLogID)
.option("upperbound", w_maxLogID)
.load()
```

The spark docs https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html says that:

> partitionColumn must be a numeric, date, or timestamp column from the table in question.

But is there some workaround to this?

Answer (score 2):

For achieving parallelism in spark JDBC data read, you have to specify numPartitions, partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound.(https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) Else spark always does one single JDBC connection and reads all the data into single partitions. In this case, only one executor is used and parallelism is not achieved.
Example.

```
spark.sqlContext.read.jdbc(url, "(select * from transaction ) as s", connectionProperties).
```

In this case, only one query is fired to databases in one of the executors, so no parallelism.
To achieve parallelism use the below code

```
spark.sqlContext.read
    .option("partitionColumn", "amount")
    .option("lowerBound", 0).option("upperBound", 1000)
    .option("numPartitions", 10)
    .jdbc(url), "( select * from transaction ) as s", connectionProperties)
```

Above query will create 10 db connections across spark executors and data is read parallelly to spark memory.

```
select * from transaction where amount>=0 and amount<100.
select * from transaction where amount>=100 and amount<200...
```

If you don't have any numeric column in the table, the workaround would be to use the row number

```
val partitionCount = 10
val partitionKey="partitionKey" 
spark.sqlContext.read
        .option("partitionColumn", partitionKey)
        .option("lowerBound", 0).option("upperBound", partitionCount)
        .option("numPartitions", partitionCount)
        .jdbc(url), s"( select mod(row_number() OVER (),$partitionCount) as $partitionKey, * from transaction ) as s", connectionProperties).drop(partitionKey)
```

The above code will create 10 DB connections across spark executors.
As we are doing mod of row number over partition count, we will always get values from 0 to 9. By doing this data is read parallelly and is evenly distributed among the partitions.
To check partitions

```
import spark.implicits._
df
  .rdd
  .mapPartitionsWithIndex { case (i, rows) => Iterator((i, rows.size)) }
  .toDF("partition_number", "number_of_records")
  .show
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** This optional field to improve performance. If your dataset is small you can skip it. Similar functionality can be achieved by using `predicates: Array[String]` argument for string columns.

```
val connectionProperties = new Properties()
connectionProperties.put("database", db)
connectionProperties.put("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")

var finaldataframe = spark.read.jdbc(
    url = url,
    table = table_name,
    predicates = Array[String]("columnA like 'A%'", "columnB like 'B%'" )
    connectionProperties = connectionProperties
)
```

---

To understand why only numeric-like column is allowed for `partitionColumn` look into how spark reads from databases.

By default spark would use a single executor to connect to database, run the query and start extracting the results. This approach is not suitable if you want to extract large datasets from database because

- only one executor is extracting data.
- The extracted data has to repartitioned/shuffled to other executors.

This can be improve if multiple executors extract **part of** data from database in parallel. Assume you want to run query `select id, prod_name from products` and this table has one million rows.
You would tell spark `numPartitions` as `4`, `partitionColumn` as `id` which is integer, `lowerbound` 1 and `upperbound` as `1000000`.
Now spark will calculate that each executor need to extract 250K records.

> (upperbound - lowerbound +1) / numPartitions
>   = (1000000 - 1 +1) / 4
>   = 250000

Using this the first executor will launch query

```
select * 
from 
  (
    select id, prod_name 
    from products
  ) 
where id >= 1 and id<=250000
```

from the second executor

```
select * 
from 
  (
    select id, prod_name 
    from products
  ) 
where id >= 250001 and id<=500000
```

And so on. This only works if the `paritionColumns` has natural ordering which can be used to calculate the partitions (in this case `(1, 250000)`, `(250001, 500000)`, `(500001, 750000)` and `(750001, 1000000)` ).  These partitions are used to calculate the predicates. This approach cannot be used with string columns because there is no natural ordering between string value.

This can be overcome if the user provides the predicates directly and spark will not have to calculate anything. For example if you want to run the query `select name, score from people` and you provide predicates `Array("name like 'a%'", "name like 'b%'")` then spark will launch queries

```
select *
from 
  (
    select name, score 
    from people
  ) where "name like 'a%'"
```

and

```
select *
from 
  (
    select name, score 
    from people
  ) where "name like 'b%'"
```